# Why does Turbotax ask to enter Form 8938: Interest II schedule even when there is no interest?

Tags: united-states, taxes, international, turbotax

Does the IRS require me to enter Form 8938: Interest II schedule even when there is no interest, or is that just Turbotax asking for unnecessary information?

[image]

The same issues arise for all other Form 8938 lines where the amount is 0.